# BeagleBone Black as kiosk go to Screen Lock

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack, power-management

I have a problem with the BeagleBoneBlack Rev A5C with Debian. I used this image: `BBB-eMMC-flasher-debian-8.3-lxqt-2gb-armhf-2016-03-20-2gb.img`. Debian 8.3 with Lxqt.

I want to develop a device for displaying a web page on full screen mode on startup and to be there for ever (the page autorefresh with some information).

Until this point, everything it's alright. I installed Midori, put it in the autostart with all the options for kiosk mode and it worked.

BUT, after sometime, the system goes black. When I move the mouse, it show the login screen. I need to disable this, I don't want to go to this screen never.

I have tried many things (installing XScreensaver, installing lxqt-powermanegement, touching the xset, etc.) and nothing seems to work.

I apologise for the bad english, not a native speaker.

Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had success using 'setterm -powersave off -blank 0' or you can try 'setterm -powersave off' at the terminal. Also, I have RevA5A & was using Angstrom.